# Table caption is not showing

Tags: tables, captions, packages, subcaption, subfig

I have the following issue in overleaf: I'm using the [CAIM_sciendo_open_article_BY4](https://sciendo.com/journal/CAIM) class, and the caption in the table

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Physical parameters of polypropylene}
\label{tab:polipropilene}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Parameter     & Value & Units \\
\hline
Melting point        & $130$--$171$   & $\unit{\celsius}$        & measured $160$ $\celsius$ \\
Density              & $855$--$946$   & $\unit{Kg}/\unit{m}^3$   & atactic: $866$ \\
%molar Heat Capacity  & $88$--$90$     & $\unit{J}/\unit{mol K}$  & \\
Thermal conductivity & $0.17$--$0.22$  & $\unit{W}/(\unit{m K})$  &  at $23$ $\celsius$ typ $0.17$ \\
Specific heat        & $581.97$--$2884.71$ & $\unit{J}/(\unit{Kg K})$ & temp. in K \\
%Tensile modulus      & $1200$         & $\unit{Mpa}$               & \\
%Flexural modulus     & $1150$         & $\unit{Mpa}$               & \\
Young's module         & $1300$--$1800$ & $\unit{N}/\unit{mm}^2=\unit{MPa}$               & \\
%Elongation           & $450$          & \textrm{\%}                  & \\
%Vicat softening temperature & $90$--$150$    & $\celsius$             & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

(but in any other table as well) is not showing. If I add the packages

```
\usepackage{subfig}
```

or

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

the caption is showing but i get the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \captionbox already defined.

Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
..                                              
                                              
l.454 ...ption@withoptargs{\caption@ibox\@gobble}}
                                              
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

May someone tell me where am I wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CAIM_Sciendo_open_article_BY4` document class appears to set the appearance of captions in a, shall we say, idiosyncratic manner. I suggest you run `\let\captionbox\relax` to effectively disable the document class's caption-related code, load the [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, and use that package's `\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator` and `\captionsetup` commands to replicate the document class's preferred formatting of captions.

Do please also make an effort to better master the `\unit`, `\qty`, `\num` and `\numrange` macros of the [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package. For sure, please use only `k` to denote "kilo", and please use only `K` to denote "Kelvin".

[image]

```
\documentclass{CAIM_Sciendo_open_article_BY4}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=\textendash, per-mode=symbol}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\let\captionbox\relax
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{dotquad}{.\quad} % period and quad
\captionsetup{labelsep=dotquad, skip=0.25\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\centering

\caption{Physical parameters of polypropylene}
\label{tab:polipropilene}

\begin{tabular}{@{} llll @{}}
\toprule
Parameter            & Value range         & Unit & \\
\midrule
Melting point        & \numrange{130}{171} & \unit{\celsius}                  & measured \qty{160}{\celsius} \\
Density              & \numrange{855}{946} & \unit{\kilogram\per\meter\cubed} & atactic: \num{866} \\
Thermal conductivity & \numrange{0.17}{0.22} & \unit{\watt\per(\meter\kelvin)}& at \qty{23}{\celsius} typ \num{0.17} \\
Specific heat        & \numrange{581.97}{2884.71} & \unit{\joule\per(\kilogram\,\kelvin)} & temp.\ in \unit{\kelvin} \\
Young's module       & \numrange{1300}{1800} & \unit{\newton\per\milli\meter\squared}${}={}$\unit{\mega\pascal} & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```